# Decode my Ex's Message

Tags: cipher

After the last message from my girlfriend (from a previous puzzle) we dated for a few months before she broke up with me. She sent me one last message before she left but I need help decoding it:

**10.4513, 7.864, 10.4513, 10.3600, 13.5984, 10.4513, 21.5645, 6.7642, 6.1077, 4.3407, 21.5645, 6.1077, 6.2173, 13.6181, 6.1941**

Hint:

> The information I used to make this was learnt from my second quarter in AP Chemistry on Periodic Properties.

Comment: Also unrelated but how do I change my username? I use the stack exchange app

Comment: you can edit your profile in your profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> IWISHINeVErKNe[Er]YOU, symbols for elements by ionization energy in eV, to make “I wish I never knew you”.

I guess the last 6.1077 is supposed to be 7.864?